# AngularJs, routing, problem creating several routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJs and very new to `ui-router`.
I seem to be having problems creating several routes. This is how I proceed, inspiring myself from a tutorial but failing to reproduce the result.
Here are my different files:
1/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

            <a href="#/">Home</a>
            <a href="#/about">About</a>
            <a href="#/contact">Contact</a>

        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/about/about.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/about/about.component.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/home/home.component.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/contact/contact.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/contact/contact.component.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2/app.js

```
angular
    .module('app', []);
```

3/about.js

```
angular
    .module('about', ['ui.router']);
```

4/about.component.js

```
const about = {
    template: '<div class="about">About</div>'
};
    
angular
    .module('about', ['ui.router'])
    .component('about', about)
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state({
            name: 'about',
            url: '/about',
            component: 'about',
            // template: "<div>About</div>"
        })
    });
```

There are 2 similar files for `home` and another 2 for `contact`.

There is obviously something wrong as we are only calling the `app` module and not the `contact, home, about` modules, but this is the way the tutorial was done.
It's not working (the different templates of each routed module are not showing) and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is the issue no routes working now?

Comment: Yes I think that is the issue. When I click on about, the template should be triggered and I should see ```About``` show up. But it does bring me to the correct url.

Comment: It seems like you bootstrap the `app` module which has no deps. On the other hand, it does nothing there. It's supposed to depend on `about` module and more instead

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be something like that, but the tutorial doesn't even show the content of the ```app.js``` file, but yet it is the only module that is called with ```ng-app```.
Could there be some code in ```app.js``` that would make this work?
How would I go about to make it depend on ```about```, ```home``` and ```contact```?

Comment: You just simply set as you did `angular.module('app',  ['home', 'about']);`

Comment: This was so simple, and yet nothing in the tutorial mentioned it. Maybe it was a given... I'm struggling with AngularJs, it is so not intuitive to me. But now I get it, it definitely makes more sense now. Thank you so much you solved it!
Don't you want it make it an official answer to get some points ? :)

Comment: Haha :) Okay. Glad to hear it helped. However, I think you should not be looking into AngularJs too much this time since it's too obsolete :)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I just got a new job, and the company I work for uses AngularJs :/
Thanks again!

Comment: It sounds like my company too where to have main product still being written in AngularJS :)

Comment: aha, so my company isn't the only one left using Angularjs, that's reassuring lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure all the modules get bootstrapped accordingly, just simply set them all as the deps for `app` module:

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['home', ...])
```

One more thing is about setting the directive attribute `ui-sref` for `<a ui-sref="home" />` to work best with `ui-router` module instead of `#/home` which works with `ngRoute`